# sp_helptext return (server internal)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am try to show sp_xml_preparedocument by using the below code

```
sp_helptext 'sp_xml_preparedocument'
```

or

```
 sp_helptext 'sys.sp_xml_preparedocument'
```

this returns :

> Text 
>  
>   (server internal)

This code work fine with another custom SP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are extended stored procedures so you cannot see the internals. They are processed in a dll rather than TSQL.

[Extended Stored Procedures](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175200%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

As @JamesZ commented, using sp_help withh return the "type" of stored procedure. In this case: 'extended stored proc'

Comment: how I can know if the stored procedure is extended  or not ?

Comment: @OsamaAbuSitta sp_help will tell you that

Comment: It is extended stored proc , 
Thanks @KarlKieninger and JamesZ